Inno setup - configuration file not found, select it manually
I would like to ask for help from more experienced developers.
I created a project using Visual Studio code 2022, using the C# language.
I tested my project by compiling, and everything works perfectly. However, I need to pass it on through an installer, which is where my problems started.
I used the Inno Setup tool to create my installer, followed the steps as always, and the installer was generated.
When running this installer, the program is installed on the machine normally. The problem starts at this point.
When trying to run the installed program, the following message is displayed:
configuration file not found, select it manually.
When I select this file manually, the program works normally.
But I wanted to make the installer already link this configuration file.
I tried to do this using this line in inno setup:
Source: "C:\Users\Tiago\Documents\New folder\Siliccom\bin\x64\Debug\Sistema\Shic .ini"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
But without success.
Thank you to anyone who can help me.
I tried including the command line:
Source: "C:\Users\Tiago\Documents\New folder\Siliccom\bin\x64\Debug\Sistema\Shic .ini"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
In the Files section, however, I was unsuccessful.
The gpt chat didn't give me good possibilities, and apparently this error message isn't as common as I thought.
I didn't find reports on the internet about this problem.
